# vue watch mapState not working

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I use a store value in my component and try to update it.The store value gets changed when I click the button, but the change is not reflected in the component output (i.e. {{query}})

```
    <template>
         span {{query}}
         button(@click='updateQuery')
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
        computed: mapState('map', [
            'query'
        ]),
        methods: {
            ...mapMutations('map', [
                'setStart'
            ]),
            updateQuery() {
                this.setStart(new Date());
            }
       }
   }
   </script>
```

store:

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        query: {},
        start: null,
        end: null
    },
    mutations: {
        setQuery(state, value) { state.query = value },
        setStart(state, value) {
            state.start = value;
            state.query.timestamp = state.query.timestamp ? state.query.timestamp : {};
            state.query.timestamp.$gte = value;
        },
        setEnd(state, value) {
            state.end = value;
            state.query.timestamp = state.query.timestamp ? state.query.timestamp : {};
            state.query.timestamp.$lte = value;
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using some kind of rendering engine in the template? maybe it's causing that effect? or a v-once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is [Vue cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) that you are adding new properties to the `query` object dynamically.

In this code:

```
state.query.timestamp = state.query.timestamp ? state.query.timestamp : {};
```

You are adding a `timestamp` property to `query` that was not previously there. It will not, therefore, be reactive. In order to work with Vue properly you need to use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

```
Vue.set(state.query, `timestamp`, state.query.timestamp ? state.query.timestamp : {})
```

Note, you will also need to do that on the next line for the `$gte` property.

Alternatively, you could initialize query object.

```
state: {
    query: {
      timestamp:{
        $gte: null,
        $lte: null
      }
    },
    start: null,
    end: null
},
```